# Why does clang require a function to be declared before it's called in a template?

Tags: c++, g++, clang++

I have the following code example (available online at [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/98f642e0709485e2)):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

struct Bar {
    int a;
};

template <class T>
void print_arg(const T& arg) {
    std::cout << arg << std::endl;    
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Bar& b) {
    os << b.a;
    return os;
}

template <class T1, class T2>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::pair<T1, T2>& pair) {
    os << "Pair(" << pair.first << ',' << pair.second << ")";
    return os;
}

int main()
{
    auto bar = Bar{1};
    print_arg(bar);
    print_arg(std::make_pair(bar, bar));
    print_arg(std::make_pair(bar, 1));
    print_arg(std::make_pair(0, 1));
}
```

The last line in the main function is what's giving me trouble. Compilation with g++ works just fine (with the exact same options as below), I launch the executable and it prints everything as expected. However, Clang++ gives me the following error:

```
$ clang++ -std=c++17 -O2 -Wall -Werror -Wpedantic main.cpp && ./a.out
main.cpp:10:15: error: call to function 'operator<<' that is neither visible in the template definition nor found by argument-dependent lookup
    std::cout << arg << std::endl;    
              ^
main.cpp:29:5: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'print_arg<std::pair<int, int> >' requested here
    print_arg(std::make_pair(0, 1));
    ^
main.cpp:19:15: note: 'operator<<' should be declared prior to the call site
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::pair<T, T>& pair) {
              ^
1 error generated.
```

Furthermore, removing the last line (commenting it out) results in Clang++ compiling everything correctly. Which, as far as I can tell, means that `std::pair<int, int>` is qualitatively different from other parameter types.

My question is, why does g++ compile it eitherway? And more importantly, why does clang think it is ok to declare `operator<<(ostream, pair<Bar, Bar>)` later, but it's not ok for `operator<<(ostream, pair<int, int>)`. Is it because the latter only includes standard and basic types?

To me the (somewhat) logical thing seems to be that defining functions only over standard/basic types is UB, but g++ silently ignores it and clang++ gives a weird-looking error message. However, that doesn't make a whole lot of sense to me and I can't find the relevant standard clause.

**Note**: I understand that moving the declaration up is what clang is asking for, but I don't understand why. I want to provide `print_arg` function in a separate header and allow the person that includes that header to specialize `operator<<` while using `print_arg`.

Comment: I don't know why g++ allows it but leaving the specialization of `operator<<` up to the user would still work. It just has to be forward declared before the `print_arg` definition.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Well, that means the user has to first declare and then include, which is sort of ugly. And to me g++'s behavior perfectly reasonable, since instantiation happens after the declaration. Eitherway, at this point I'm just curious what the hell is going on here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C++ standard says that unqualified names are looked up in two ways. According to [Clang's documentation on language compatibility](https://clang.llvm.org/compatibility.html#dep_lookup):

> First, the compiler does unqualified lookup in the scope where the
>   name was written. For a template, this means the lookup is done at the
>   point where the template is defined, not where it's instantiated.
>
> Second, if the name is called like a function, then the compiler also
>   does argument-dependent lookup (ADL). Sometimes unqualified lookup can
>   suppress ADL; In ADL, the compiler looks at the types of all the
>   arguments to the call. When it finds a class type, it looks up the
>   name in that class's namespace; the result is all the declarations it
>   finds in those namespaces, plus the declarations from unqualified
>   lookup. However, the compiler doesn't do ADL until it knows all the
>   argument types.

There are two ways to fix this problem:

1. Make sure the function you want to call is declared before the template that might call it. This is the only option if none of its argument types contain classes. You can do this either by moving the template definition, or by moving the function definition, or by adding a forward declaration of the function before the template.
2. Move the function into the same namespace as one of its arguments so
   that ADL applies.

↳ see [basic.lookup.argdep](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lookup) and [temp.dep.candidate](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.dep.candidate)

Comment: Thanks a lot, this makes a whole lot more sense than what I came up with. Guess I just didn't catch that there are no arguments from the global namespace when operator<< is called. Also I suppose it makes a lot of sense to ignore what the user of a template has defined, so it doesn't conflict with what the author defined in the namespace of the template.

Comment: The text you quote is from the LLVM documentation, not the standard. And the second paragraph is not relevant: if you look at the original source in the LLVM documentation, it refers to basic.lookup.argdep/3 for the list of situations where unqualified lookup suppresses ADL, and none of them apply to the code in the question

Comment: I appreciate the information; I referenced the clang explanation since it seemed relevant to the issue at hand. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60242553/499581) linked to what looks like more or less the same thing, so maybe it's incorrect as well. If you have an official link for [temp.dep.res]/1 you’ve mentioned that might be helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Look into [Language Compatibility : Unqualified lookup in templates](https://clang.llvm.org/compatibility.html#dep_lookup) section. It explains exactly this case.

The summary is `GCC` compiles buggy code, while clang follows the standard.

Answer (score 3):

The relevant text in the Standard is C++17 [temp.dep.res]/1:

> In resolving dependent names, names from the following sources are considered:
>
> - Declarations that are visible at the point of definition of the template.
> - Declarations from namespaces associated with the types of the function arguments both from the instantiation context and from the definition context.

(This is elaborated on by temp.dep.candidate/1).

The problem situation in this code is the call `std::cout << arg` inside `print_arg`.  The name being looked up is `operator<<`. This is a *dependent name* because it's a function call with an argument whose type depends on a template parameter.

The *definition context* is the context where this expression occurs, i.e. inside `print_arg`.  Any declaration visible at this point is considered.

The *instantiation context* is defined by [temp.point]; in this code `print_arg` was called from `main()` so the instantiation context is at namespace scope after the end of `main()`. However , as covered by the second bullet point above,  the only names considered from the instantiation context are those found by argument-dependent lookup.

The argument of `std::pair<Bar, int>` or `std::pair<Bar, Bar>` has ADL classes of `pair` (therefore namespace `std`), and `Bar` (therefore the global namespace). ADL of a template type does include any template parameter types.

However in the case `std::pair<int, int>` the only ADL namespace is `std`, therefore `::operator<<` is not found.

---

Important point to understand: the `operator<<(ostream, pair)` function was found due to the  global namespace being searched by ADL, which happened because `Bar`'s use added the global namespace to the search list, even though this function doesn't mention `Bar` specifically.  If `Bar` were in some other namespace then all three calls should fail to compile.

Because of the reasons covered here, it's normally recommended to not add operator overloads unless at least one parameter is in a namespace defined by the user. Then it will always be found by ADL for the corresponding arguments.  It would be preferable to define your library in such a way that it does not overload for `(ostream, pair)` .